# Recursive function not working in Angular/Typescript: "is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions"

Tags: typescript

I'm converting a recursive function that works in Dart into TypeScript, for an Angular project. The offending line is

```js
return this.reduceNumber(firstNameNumberReduced);
```

The error message is

```
'reduceNumber' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
```

The complete function is

```js
reduceNumber(firstNameNumber: number = 0) {
    var firstNameNumberReduced: number = 0;
    if (firstNameNumber == 11 || firstNameNumber == 22 || firstNameNumber <= 9) {
      return firstNameNumber; // we're done
    } else if (firstNameNumber > 9) {
      var firstNameNumberCompoundList = firstNameNumber.toString().split(""); // string splits into strings, not integers
      firstNameNumberCompoundList.forEach((element) => {
        // iterate over the list
        var notAstring = parseInt(element);
        firstNameNumberReduced = firstNameNumberReduced + notAstring; 
      });
      return this.reduceNumber(firstNameNumberReduced); // recursive, ERROR HERE
    } else {
      console.error("Error in reduceNumber function.");
      return
    }
  }
```

The error message is saying two things. It's saying that the returned value doesn't have a type. But I set the type of the returned variable `firstNameNumberReduced`:

```js
var firstNameNumberReduced: number = 0;
```

The second error message says that the return expression directly calls the function recursively. Well, yeah, that's what I'm trying to do! :-)

Comment: add the return type to your function definition. `reduceNumber(firstNameNumber: number = 0): number {}`

Comment: Also... we have this `firstNameNumber: number` which is of type `number`, still in the code we have `var firstNameNumberCompoundList = firstNameNumber.toString().split("");`... any reason, why ??

Comment: @NalinRanjan, the app does Kabbalah numerology. It converts the letters of your name into numbers and then tells you your fortune. You can download with the Flutter version on Android or web https://kabbalah-numerology.web.app/#/.

Comment: Oh Ok...!!! I was thinking in terms of the type alone...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @about14sheep!

```
reduceNumber(firstNameNumber: number = 0): number {
   // code
}
```

That worked. I had no idea that you can specify the return type of a function.